# What is SAL_CALL in c++?

Tags: c++, c, linux

can any one explain me briefly.

What is SAL_CALL in c++?

Comment: This question, and its factual, well-documented, upvoted answer, were directly useful to me. It does not seem likely to cause debate etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a `#define` used in OpenOffice.org. It's defined in `sal/inc/sal/types.h` as one of:

```
#define SAL_CALL
#define SAL_CALL __cdecl
```

depending on the platform being compiled for. It looks like it's set to the latter only when `_MSC_VER` (for Microsoft) is defined.

It's used when specifying functions like:

```
virtual void SAL_CALL acquire() throw () { ++m_nRefCount; }
```

which would be morphed into:

```
virtual void acquire() throw () { ++m_nRefCount; }
```

for regular compilers and:

```
virtual void __cdecl acquire() throw () { ++m_nRefCount; }
```

for Microsoft.

As to what `__cdecl` means to the Microsoft compiler, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), extracted below:

---

**Microsoft Specific**

This is the default calling convention for C and C++ programs. Because the stack is cleaned up by the caller, it can do `vararg` functions. The `__cdecl` calling convention creates larger executables than `__stdcall`, because it requires each function call to include stack cleanup code. The following list shows the implementation of this calling convention.

```
+------------------------+----------------------------+
| Element                | Implementation             |
+------------------------+----------------------------+
| Argument-passing order | Right to left              |
+------------------------+----------------------------+
| Stack-maintenance      | Calling function pops the  |
|   responsibility       |   arguments from the stack |
+------------------------+----------------------------+
| Name-decoration        | Underscore character (_)   |
|   convention           |   is prefixed to names     |
+------------------------+----------------------------+
| Case-translation       | No case translation        |
|   convention           |   performed                |
+------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: very thanks to ...definitly it will help me..

Answer (score 0):

It's not anything special to C++.  It's some kind of project-specific preprocessor macro.  I would guess that it's some kind of special calling convention.  I found [one preprocessor macro in the Linux kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/ia64/include/asm/sal.h#L62), which appears to be some kind of 64-bit optimized calling convention.  According to the comment at the top of that file, "SAL" stands for "System Abstraction Layer."